# If $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = c \vert xy \vert$ then find $c$ and $P[X^2 > Y^2]$

Tags: probability

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with joint probability function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=c \vert xy \vert$ if $-N <x < y < N$ and $0$ in other case, with $N$ a natural number. Find the value of $c$ and $P[X^2 > Y^2]$.

I think $c=\frac{4}{N^4}$, is my procedure correct?

$$ \int_{-N}^N \int_{-N}^y c \vert x \vert \vert y \vert dx dy = c [\int_{-N}^0 \int_{-N}^y  (-x)(-y) dx dy + \int_{0}^N (\int_{-N}^0(-x)(y)dx +  \int_{0}^y xy dx )dy]$$
$$ c [\int_{-N}^0 (y^3/2 - y N^2/2)  dy + \int_{0}^N (N^2 y /2 +  y^3/2 )dy] = c[ N^4/8 - N^4/4 + N^4/4 + N^4/8    ]=cN^4/4$$

then $c=4/N^4$.

And I don't know how to calculate $P[X^2 > Y^2]$, I was thinking in calculating $X-Y$, $X+Y$, then $(X-Y)(X+Y)$, but maybe there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} &c [\int_{-N}^0 (y^3/2 - y N^2/2)  dy + \int_{0}^N (N^2 y /2 +  y^3/2 )dy] \\&=c\left[\left[\frac{y^4}{8}-\frac{y^2N^2}{4} \right]_{-N}^0 +  \left[\frac{y^2N^2}{4} +\frac{y^4}{8}\right]_{0}^N\right]\\&= c[ \color{red}-N^4/8 \color{red}+ N^4/4 + N^4/4 + N^4/8    ]\\&=\frac{cN^4}{2}
\end{align}
Hence,
$$c = \frac2{N^4}.$$

Remark: a quicker way to compute $c$ is to assume that the domain is extended to $[-N,N]^2$ by symmetry, and evaluating $$4\hat{c
} \int_0^N \int_0^N xy\,\, dxdy = 1$$

$$ \hat{c}N^2 =1 $$

$$\hat{c} = \frac1{N^2}$$

By symmetry, $$c = 2\hat{c}=\frac2{N^2}$$

\begin{align}
P(X^2 > Y^2) &= P((X-Y)(X+Y)>0) \\
&= P(X+Y <0), \text{since we know } X<Y \\
&=P(Y<-X) \\
&= 2P(0<Y <-X)\\
&= 2 \int_{-N}^0 \int_0^{-x}c(-x)(y)\, \,dydx
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, you need to integrate $c|xy|$ over the region of $-N<x<y<N$,

[image]

set it equal to $1$, and solve for $c$. You seem to know how to do this, except you got the signs of the first two parts wrong. The integral turns out to be $c N^4/2$, and therefore, $c=2/N^4$.

For the second part, you need to integrate $c|xy|$ over the region $(-N<x<y<N) \cap (x^2>y^2)$. Note that $x^2>y^2$ implies $|x|>|y|$, so the region would look like this:

[image]

Note that this is half of the region of nonzero probability, and the probability density function is symmetric across the boundary $|x|=|y|$, and therefore, the integral should end up being $1/2$. You can check that by direct integration.